# Get current page URL from a firefox sidebar extension

Tags: firefox, url, xul, sidebar

I'm writing a sidebar extension for Firefox and need a way to get the URL of the current page so I can check it against a database and display the results. How can I do this?

Comment: I think this question is about the old-school Firefox sidebars, and not the new [sidebar SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_sidebar).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
window.top.getBrowser().selectedBrowser.contentWindow.location.href;
```

might work, otherwise I think you need to use:

```
var mainWindow = window.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                   .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIWebNavigation)
                   .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDocShellTreeItem)
                   .rootTreeItem
                   .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                   .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow);

mainWindow.getBrowser().selectedBrowser.contentWindow.location.href;
```

Comment: You may need to replace `Components.interfaces` to just `Ci` everywhere in the above answer. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558983/nsisockettransportservice-using-firefox-addon-sdk for more and also add `const {Ci, components} = require("chrome")` to the top of your script.

Answer (score 20):

I stumbled over this post while looking for an answer to the same question.

Actually I think it's as easy as

```
alert(window.content.location.href)
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.content

Comment: This seems to work if you're overlaying the main browser window (browser.xul) but I don't know if it will work in other cases.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work fine for me

```
function getCurrentURL(){

    var currentWindow = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator).getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");

    var currBrowser = currentWindow.getBrowser();
    var currURL = currBrowser.currentURI.spec;

    return currURL;
}
```

Comment: you should add `function getCurrentURL(){` and `}` to the code layout. They're part of the code.

Comment: this is a good choice as when a new tab is open is gets that URL instead in case of @Wimmel it doesn't. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Working_with_windows_in_chrome_code

If you need to access the main browser from the code running in a sidebar, you'll something like what Wimmel posted, except the last line could be simplified to

```
mainWindow.content.location.href
```

(alternatively you could use 's API returning an nsIURI).

Depending on your task, it might make sense to run the code in the browser window instead (e.g. in a page load handler), then it can access the current page via the `content` shortcut and the sidebar via `document.getElementById("sidebar").contentDocument` or `.contentWindow`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need only **domain** and **subdomain**;

Usage;

```
PageDomain.getDomain(); // stackoverflow.com
PageDomain.getSubDomain(); //  abc.stackoverflow.com
```

Code;

```
PageDomain = {

getDomain : function() {
    var docum = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator).getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");
    var domain = PageDomain.extractDomain(new String(docum.location));
    return domain;
},
getSubDomain : function() {
    var docum = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator).getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");
    var subDomain = PageDomain.extractSubDomain(new String(docum.location));
    return subDomain;
},
 extractDomain: function(host) {
        var s;

        // Credits to Chris Zarate
        host=host.replace('http:\/\/','');
        host=host.replace('https:\/\/','');
        re=new RegExp("([^/]+)");
        host=host.match(re)[1];
        host=host.split('.');

        if(host[2]!=null) {
          s=host[host.length-2]+'.'+host[host.length-1];
          domains='ab.ca|ac.ac|ac.at|ac.be|ac.cn|ac.il|ac.in|ac.jp|ac.kr|ac.nz|ac.th|ac.uk|ac.za|adm.br|adv.br|agro.pl|ah.cn|aid.pl|alt.za|am.br|arq.br|art.br|arts.ro|asn.au|asso.fr|asso.mc|atm.pl|auto.pl|bbs.tr|bc.ca|bio.br|biz.pl|bj.cn|br.com|cn.com|cng.br|cnt.br|co.ac|co.at|co.il|co.in|co.jp|co.kr|co.nz|co.th|co.uk|co.za|com.au|com.br|com.cn|com.ec|com.fr|com.hk|com.mm|com.mx|com.pl|com.ro|com.ru|com.sg|com.tr|com.tw|cq.cn|cri.nz|de.com|ecn.br|edu.au|edu.cn|edu.hk|edu.mm|edu.mx|edu.pl|edu.tr|edu.za|eng.br|ernet.in|esp.br|etc.br|eti.br|eu.com|eu.lv|fin.ec|firm.ro|fm.br|fot.br|fst.br|g12.br|gb.com|gb.net|gd.cn|gen.nz|gmina.pl|go.jp|go.kr|go.th|gob.mx|gov.br|gov.cn|gov.ec|gov.il|gov.in|gov.mm|gov.mx|gov.sg|gov.tr|gov.za|govt.nz|gs.cn|gsm.pl|gv.ac|gv.at|gx.cn|gz.cn|hb.cn|he.cn|hi.cn|hk.cn|hl.cn|hn.cn|hu.com|idv.tw|ind.br|inf.br|info.pl|info.ro|iwi.nz|jl.cn|jor.br|jpn.com|js.cn|k12.il|k12.tr|lel.br|ln.cn|ltd.uk|mail.pl|maori.nz|mb.ca|me.uk|med.br|med.ec|media.pl|mi.th|miasta.pl|mil.br|mil.ec|mil.nz|mil.pl|mil.tr|mil.za|mo.cn|muni.il|nb.ca|ne.jp|ne.kr|net.au|net.br|net.cn|net.ec|net.hk|net.il|net.in|net.mm|net.mx|net.nz|net.pl|net.ru|net.sg|net.th|net.tr|net.tw|net.za|nf.ca|ngo.za|nm.cn|nm.kr|no.com|nom.br|nom.pl|nom.ro|nom.za|ns.ca|nt.ca|nt.ro|ntr.br|nx.cn|odo.br|on.ca|or.ac|or.at|or.jp|or.kr|or.th|org.au|org.br|org.cn|org.ec|org.hk|org.il|org.mm|org.mx|org.nz|org.pl|org.ro|org.ru|org.sg|org.tr|org.tw|org.uk|org.za|pc.pl|pe.ca|plc.uk|ppg.br|presse.fr|priv.pl|pro.br|psc.br|psi.br|qc.ca|qc.com|qh.cn|re.kr|realestate.pl|rec.br|rec.ro|rel.pl|res.in|ru.com|sa.com|sc.cn|school.nz|school.za|se.com|se.net|sh.cn|shop.pl|sk.ca|sklep.pl|slg.br|sn.cn|sos.pl|store.ro|targi.pl|tj.cn|tm.fr|tm.mc|tm.pl|tm.ro|tm.za|tmp.br|tourism.pl|travel.pl|tur.br|turystyka.pl|tv.br|tw.cn|uk.co|uk.com|uk.net|us.com|uy.com|vet.br|web.za|web.com|www.ro|xj.cn|xz.cn|yk.ca|yn.cn|za.com';
          domains=domains.split('|');
          for(var i=0;i<domains.length;i++) {
            if(s==domains[i]) {
              s=host[host.length-3]+'.'+s;
              break;
            }
          }
        } else {
          s=host.join('.');
        }
        // Thanks Chris
        return s;
      },

      extractSubDomain:function(host){
          host=host.replace('http:\/\/','');
          host=host.replace('https:\/\/','');
          re=new RegExp("([^/]+)");
          host=host.match(re)[1];
          return host;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**From a Firefox extension popup ;**

You'll need

```
"permissions": [
  "activeTab"
]
```

in your manifest or possibly `tabs` instead of `activeTab`

```
async function getCurrentTabUrl(){
    let tabs = await browser.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}) ;
    return tabs[0].url ;
}

let hostUrl = await getCurrentTab();
alert(hostUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works from a firefox "popup" extension.

```
browser.tabs.query({active: true, windowId: browser.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT})
    .then(tabs => browser.tabs.get(tabs[0].id))
    .then(tab => {
    console.log(tab);    
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Hallo,

I have tried to implement this in JavaScript, because I need that in my project too, but all three possible solutions didn't work. I have also implemented a small site to test it, but this also didn't work.

Here is the source code of the small site:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Fall1 () {

    alert(window.top.getBrowser().selectedBrowser.contentWindow.location.href);
}

function Fall2() {
var mainWindow = window.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                   .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIWebNavigation)
                   .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDocShellTreeItem)
                   .rootTreeItem
                   .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                   .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow);

alert(mainWindow.getBrowser().selectedBrowser.contentWindow.location.href);
}

function Fall3() {
alert(document.getElementById("sidebar").contentWindow.location.href);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="Probe" action="">

<input type="button" value="Fall1"
onclick="Fall1()">

<input type="button" value="Fall2"
onclick="Fall2()">

<input type="button" value="Fall3"
onclick="Fall13()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Javascript in a webpage doesn't behave the same way as Javascript in a Firefox addon. When you're writing a webpage, `document` refers to that webpage. When you're writing an addon, `document` refers to the XUL document that the script is embedded in.