# Getting current browser url in Firefox Addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I within a panel and I want to get the current browser URL. Nothing so far works. Here's what I've tested:

Only thing that even returns anything, I get something like `resource://jid0-18z0ptaugyu0arjkaoywztggyzg-at-jetpack/` and then my current panel resource. Obviously this is a scope problem but I don't know how to refer to the actual browser.

```
window.location.href
```

I've tried literally everything in the biggest Stack Overflow thread on this: [Get current page URL from a firefox sidebar extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410411/get-current-page-url-from-a-firefox-sidebar-extension). None of them return anything.

If it helps, I am using the Firefox Addon Builder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
// you need to use this service first
var windowsService = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1'].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);

// window object representing the most recent (active) instance of Firefox
var currentWindow = windowsService.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');

// most recent (active) browser object - that's the document frame inside the chrome
var browser = currentWindow.getBrowser();

// object containing all the data about an address displayed in the browser
var uri = browser.currentURI;

// textual representation of the actual full URL displayed in the browser
var url = uri.spec;
```

Comment: @anunixercoder I doubt it will work. This is obsolete. If you want to get current URL in current Firefox extension, just add content script (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_scripts) and ask directly for `document.location` from it.

Answer (score 17):

### getting the URL from a sidebar or popup

To retrieve the URL from a [sidebar or popup requires tab permissions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs)

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
```

then you need to find the tab you want. If you just want the active tab this would work fine, [for anything more advanced I'd look here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/query).

```
function getPage(){
  browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true})
    .then((tabs) => {
      console.log(tabs[0].url);
  })
}
```

### getting the URL from injected javascript

If you want the URL for a background task I suggest this method as you do not need permissions.

this will give you a background script and then inject a script onto almost any webpage on the internet.

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},

"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.*"],
      "js": ["modify-page/URL.js"]
    }
  ],
```

this will be injected into webpages through the URL js and will send a message to your background js to use.

```
var service= browser.runtime.connect({name:"port-from-cs"});

service.postMessage({location: document.URL});
```

This code is in your background js and will collect each new page's url as it changes.

```
var portFromCS;

function connected(p) {
  portFromCS = p;
  portFromCS.onMessage.addListener(function(m) {
    if(m.location !== undefined){
      console.log(m.location);
    }
  });
}

browser.runtime.onConnect.addListener(connected);
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe using the API `tabs` from SDK can do this:

```
// Get the active tab's title.
var tabs = require("tabs");
console.log("title of active tab is " + tabs.activeTab.title);
```

Answer (score 1):

The API shows that in order to retrieve the current tabs URL

```
   var URL = require('sdk/url').URL;
   var tabs = require('sdk/tabs');
   var url = URL(tabs.activeTab.url);

   console.log('active: ' + tabs.activeTab.url);
```

This will print to the console: " active: http://www.example.com  "

Answer (score 0):

**window** gives you the current window.  **top** gives you the outermost frame.

Comment: `window.top.location.href` returns the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

For the addon you can use following code to get URL from the address bar

Javascript code:

```
function Doit(){
   var link = window.top.getBrowser().selectedBrowser.contentWindow.location.href;
   alert (link); 
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div onclick = "Doit()">Generate URL</div>
```

This will generate the URL presented on the present tab of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can now access the current URL directly via document.location.  Example:

```
console.log(`Current URL is ${document.location}`);
```

The special magic is no longer required.