# Get current URL

Tags: javascript, sdk, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm looking to get the current url of the selected tab in firefox, I've got a Firefox SDK Panel directed at a contentURL and I've been using Javascript to try and fetch the current url;

```
window.content.location.href
```

But unfortunately it does not work unless im on my contentURL page any other pages and it displays nothing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the URL like this

```
var url = require('sdk/tabs').activeTab.url;
```

This works only inside your *add-on code*, not inside *content scripts*. For the difference see [this guide](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/two-types-of-scripts.html).

If you want to trigger the lookup from the content script and/or want to use the URL in the content script, you will have to [communicate using "port"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/using-port.html).

Here is an example in which the url of the current tab is displayed in the panel upon clicking a button.

lib/main.js (add-on code):

```
const data = require('sdk/self').data;

var panel = require('sdk/panel').Panel({
    contentURL: data.url('panel.html'),
    contentScriptFile: data.url('panel.js')
});

panel.port.on('get url', function () {
    panel.port.emit('return url', require('sdk/tabs').activeTab.url);
});

panel.show();
```

data/panel.js (content script):

```
var button = document.getElementById('button');
var urlspan = document.getElementById('url');

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    self.port.emit('get url');
});

self.port.on('return url', function (url) {
    urlspan.textContent = url;
});
```

data/panel.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>panel</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="button">
      Get Current URL
    </button>
    <br>
    Current URL: <span id="url"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible to append that to the ContentURL on click of a button? Sorry, i don't know much about writing sdk

Comment: Append what to the ContentURL? And what sort of button do you mean? Inside your panel?

Comment: Yeah pretty much i would have a button on a html form "Get Current URL" then it would get the selected tab url and append it to the url ex "www.domain.com/geturl.php?url=CurrentURL"

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example. The main point is how the URL is passed between add-on code and content script using "port".

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks Martin Puppe, i appreciate all the time you've spent to help me.

Comment: One other question if i goto another page in the panel and then go back or refresh the page the button doesn't work, why does it do that?

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript:

```
window.location.href
```

In php:

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I tried both and they only return the contentURL of the SDK panel

Comment: Okey, may this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594576/getting-current-browser-url-in-firefox-addon

Comment: I've searched all over stackoverflow and im still unable to solve the problem, the only one i've had luck with is window.content.location.href and it only works on my contentURL page, once i try it on another page it does not alert me anything.